# Modifying Page Layout for a Publishing site page

Tags: publishing-page, 2007

I am working with a group to modify a page that is using the Basic Web Part Page layout for MOSS 2007 with publishing enabled.   Our developers have created a master page that repositions the site title.  Typically it would sit in the upper right of header.  In this case the site title is underneath the top nav.  I would like to remove from the layout.  However, I would like to avoid ghosting a new master page for this site to use.  I would like to create a new layout that not only removes/hides the site title but the global bread crumb as well.  Any assistance much appreciated.

Paul

Answer (score 1):

To create a new page layout that removes/hides the site title and other elements you could copy an existing page layout and add empty asp:Content elements that override the relevant ones in the masterpage. For example the following code would remove the site title from a page layout:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderSiteName" runat="server" />
```

The global breadcrumb can be removed in a similar manner using the PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb content placeholder.

To deploy your new page layout I would recommend using a feature to ensure the files are unghosted. Chris O'Brian has a good post on this at [Deploying master pages and page layouts as a feature](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2007/04/deploying-master-pages-and-page-layouts.html)

Comment: Ari,

So this would be added to directly to the layout? I am seeing this error now:
"Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page."

Comment: Paul, yes this should go directly into a page layout. The error makes it sound like the layout isn't attached to a master page correctly or doesn't only contain asp:Content controls. Also are you creating a new publishing page layout or trying to edit the page directly?

Comment: Interesting.  Editing page directly.  This sounds like I need to edit the layout directly using a copy of the page layout I want to reuse.  In my case something similar to the Basic Web Part Page that is available for publishing sites.

Comment: this worked well.  NO I just need to get rid of the site logo

Answer (score 0):

Your question has multiple questions in itself... correct me if I missed any

1) You would like to show/hide Site title/Breadcrumb for certian pages?

**easiest way:** use CSS classes to hide and show the site title / breadcrumb

Almost every control on Master page has a css class assigned to it, so we can simple add a content editor webpart and using the source editor we can add the style tags

ex

.<>
{

display : none;

}

**Style library deployment :**

Break the inheritance of the master page and duplicate the existing master page and modify .change the master page for that Page layout Or Page (bt detaching the Page layout)

WSP Builder :
duplicate the existing master page and modify and deploy in the layouts.

NOTE : CHANGES TO THE MASTER IS NOT EASY, YOU HAVE DEPLOY IT EVERYTIME :)

.change the master page for that Page layout Or Page (bt detaching the Page layout)

-> Avoid Ghosting of the new master page?? ... I assume you don't want to unghost the masterpage... is the current master page deployed in layouts or style library???

if it's in layouts...then it comes from the file sytem and I suggest osue CSS classes approach if it resolves or use WSP option...Have a look at blob cache..but I don;t think it would help for master pages :))